# Getting all children of specific page type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver, episerver-8

I have the following tree in EPI CMS:

```
[Root]
.
.
--[Lobby] ID=1
  --Foo1
  --Foo2
  --Foo3
  --[ContainerOfSubFoo] ID=2
    --SubFoo1
    --SubFoo2
    --SubFoo3
```

I want when I edit Foo1, to have check boxes of all the SubFoo's.

What I have now is this:

```
private static List<SelectItem> GetSubFoos()
    {

        PageReference pRef = new PageReference(2); //(ID=2 is my container page - ContainerOfSubFoo)
        PageData root = DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(pRef);
        var pages = DataFactory.Instance.GetChildren<Models.Pages.SubFoo>(root.ContentLink);

        List<SelectItem> targetsList = new List<SelectItem>();

        foreach (var target in pages)
        {
            targetsList.Add(new SelectItem() { Value = target.ContentLink.ID.ToString(), Text = target.SubFooProperty });
        }

        return targetsList;
    }
```

This works fine but I don't want to use ID=2, I want the GetSubFoos to go "up" (to Lobby) then go "down" to the first ContainerOfSubFoo and get all the children of SubFooType

The GetSubFoo method is on the Foo class
I can provide the code of the SelectionFactory if needed.

> Another problem I see now is that the checkbox "V" does not save :/
>   (the string is saved with the values comma seperated but the checkboxes
>   are all unchecked

this was solved by adding .ToString() for the ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within the selection factory, you can obtain the current content via a handy extension method EPiServer.Cms.Shell.Extensions.**FindOwnerContent()** on the ExtendedMetadata that is passed in by EPiServer:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ISelectItem> GetSelections(ExtendedMetadata metadata)
{
    var selections = new List<SelectItem>();
    var contentRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();

    var ownerContent = metadata.FindOwnerContent();

    if (ownerContent is Foo)
    {
        var containerRoot = contentRepository.GetChildren<ContainerOfSubFoo>(ownerContent.ParentLink).FirstOrDefault();
        var pageOptions = contentRepository.GetChildren<SubFoo>(containerRoot.ContentLink);
        foreach (var target in pageOptions)
        {
            selections.Add(new SelectItem() { Value = target.ContentLink.ID.ToString(), Text = target.SubFooProperty });
        }
    }

    return selections;
}
```

You can then traverse the page tree to find what you need.

Comment: Where is the extension method .FindOwnerContent?

Comment: FindOwnerContent() is in the EPiServer.Cms.Shell.Extensions namespace - answer updated